# Cannot export 900mb collection from Mongodb with Compass

Tags: mongodb

We built a sample database on localhost with a collection that has about 13k records - 917MB size. When trying to export this collection, Compass gets stuck. What are we missing?

Environment: Mongodb 4.2.3, Mongo Compass 1.20.5 on Mac

When using Mongo Compass

[image]

The same works with `mongoexport`

```
mongoexport --db cord --collection allpapers --out allpapers.json
```

Comment: `mongoexport` does not check to see if your db or collection within that db exists, only if it connect at all:  `mongoexport --uri="mongodb://localhost:37017/notAppearingInThisFilm" -c notAppearingInThisFilm
2020-03-19T20:16:53.231-0400    connected to: mongodb://localhost:37017/notAppearingInThisFilm
2020-03-19T20:16:53.234-0400    exported 0 records`
Are you sure `cord` is the exact name of the DB and `allarticles` is the collection?

Comment: Just magnified your screenshot.  I think your collection is named `allpapers` not `allarticles`.

Comment: Thank @BuzzMoschetti there was a typo in my command line and the "mongoexport' command worked. Compass still fails. Will edit my question.

Comment: Try changing the Compass output file to `/tmp/foo`.   The command line version is not writing to exactly the same file as Compass.   Perhaps there is a local file system lock/issue.